# Pip or Django install log files?

Tags: django, ubuntu, pip

Where are the logs for pip? I am trying to find out when or what user had updated Django and can't seem to find the install log. Does pip not keep this and require you to always install with --log? Maybe there is a log file for Django but I can't seem to find that either to give me the time date it was installed. The OS in reference is Ubuntu server 12.14. Any insight would be helpful and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify `-- log` explicitly when using `pip`, it will, by default, write logs to `$HOME/.pip/pip.log` on linux. But, it opens the log file in `w` file mode, which means it overwrites everything in the log file each time pip is called.

Hope that helps.

Comment: oh bummer, doesn't amend it like I had hoped. Thank you for the quick response!